# Azure Graph query -database,owner info from VMs in Azure

Tags: azure-resource-graph

ok so i am able to retrieve database owners from each VM using this code snippet:

```
SELECT 
  @@SERVERNAME AS [SQL Server],
  name AS [Database],
  SUSR_SNAME(owner_sid) AS [Owner],
  CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('LOCAL_NET_ADDRESS') AS varchar(15)) AS [IP Address]
FROM 
  sys.databases;
```

I am trying to create a general kql query in Azure Resource graph to do this across a subscription.

```
Resources 
| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
| where subscriptionId == '<subscription-id>'
| project Server=tostring(properties.serverName), Database=tostring(name), Owner=tostring(properties.owner), Id=tostring(id)
| join (
    Resources 
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers'
    | where subscriptionId == '<subscription-id>'
    | project Server=tostring(name), IpAddress=tostring(properties.preferredIpAddress)
    ) on $left.Server == $right.Server
| project Server, Database, Owner, IpAddress
```

it does NOT return any results. what am i doing wrong?